# Name does not exist even though declared

Tags: c#

**My Code**

```
static int IntCheck(string num)
{
    int value;
    if (!int.TryParse(num, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am sorry, I thought I said integer, let me check...");
        Console.WriteLine("Checking...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Yup, I did, please try that again, this time with an integer");
        int NewValue = IntCheck(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
        int NewValue = value;
    }
    return NewValue;
 }
```

**The Error**

> The name 'NewValue' does not exist in the current context (Line 33)

Comment: Define your `NewValue` top of your method. Since both definitions of `NewValue` are inside of `if` and `else` blocks, they are not reachable from outside of them.

Comment: Side note: before asking question about compiler error it is always good idea to check what MSDN says about it - i.e. in this case [CS0103](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx): "This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a `try` or `if` block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code block or a separate code block,"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare it outside

```
static int IntCheck(string num)
{
    int value;
    int NewValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(num, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am sorry, I thought I said integer, let me check...");
        Console.WriteLine("Checking...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Yup, I did, please try that again, this time with an integer");
        NewValue = IntCheck(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
        NewValue = value;
    }
    return NewValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

NewValue is scoped inside the `if` and `else` block.  You need to move the declaration outside the blocks.

```
static int IntCheck(string num)
{
    int value;
    int NewValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(num, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am sorry, I thought I said integer, let me check...");
        Console.WriteLine("Checking...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Yup, I did, please try that again, this time with an integer");
        NewValue = IntCheck(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else
    {
        NewValue = value;
    }
    return NewValue;
 }
```